# Query with filter on a Key field and another (string) field very slow on App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an entity `Kind A` with around 1.3 million entities. It has several fields, two of which I use as filters in a Datastore query - `K` (which is a Key) and `S` (which is a string).

I perform the following query, and it takes it almost 8 seconds to complete:

`SELECT * FROM A WHERE K=KEY('...') AND S='...' LIMIT 1`

(I do this by constructing a query with filters in java, but it works just as slow in GQL.)

Is this reasonable? Can this be improved in any way?

Replacing the key query with other fields (or removing completely), speeds things up. Does it make sense to save the key field as a string, and query on that instead of on the original Key type field?

Comment: Do you have an explicit index on those two fields together?

Comment: Why do you use a key as a property instead of using an entity's `id` or `name`? A key is much longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please send your index.yaml file, or at least paste all the indexes for Kind A?  My initial feeling is that you don't have a proper index for K and S, so it's doing a full table scan or using another index to project the results.  Check out https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes for an explanation.

If you're still banging your head, I would suggest turning appstats on and determining the slowness from the visuals on your local dev server (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats).

Finally, I wanted to point out that single property lookups are fast in App Engine, so either K= or S= lookups would be fast.  Together, they require special attention (indexing, memcache, etc.).

Comment: Good answer.  Specifically, if you aren't using a custom index for this query, it will attempt a "zig-zag" query on the separate K and S indexes, which could involve very many look-ups as it finds a matching K, then finds the next matching S, and goes back and forth in key order until it finds one key that matches both.  (I'd guess you have many records that match one or the other and not both.)  With a custom index, the index will be sorted by K then S (then key), and all results for the full query will be adjacent in the index, making for a fast return.

Comment: Thanks! I've wasn't aware of the zig-zag query, or that full table scans are even relevant in the App Engine Datastore (are they?). I thought the query worked because I had the exact index (while I only had an index at a different order and with another field). After adding the proper index, things sped up significantly.